# What is "label" in cayley quads?

Tags: go, graph, cayley

I already tried, to look in https://godoc.org/github.com/cayleygraph/cayley/quad but cant find the definition of it and it's uses.

I will appreciate any advice and recommendation, thanks.

Comment: What with the downvotes? Any explanation what's wrong with question?

Comment: I guess that it is not that clear, what your actual question is. Whether you wanted to know more about labels or simply wanted to know the value of the constant `quad.Label`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quads in caylay are an implementation of https://www.w3.org/TR/n-quads/

While triplets only allow subject, predicate and object:

```
:subject :predicate :object .

:spiderman :relationship/enemyOf :green-goblin .
```

Quads add the optional context label which can be used to further describe the relationship or base of knowledge.

```
:subject :predicate :object :label .

:spiderman :relationship/enemyOf :green-goblin :graphs/spiderman .
```

Comment: Additional resource: https://discourse.cayley.io/t/beginners-guide-to-schema-design-working-thread/436/11